# Python: lil_matrix vs csr_matrix in extremely large sparse matrices

Tags: python, sparse-matrix

I want to build an extremely large sparse matrix incrementally. The problem is that `lil_matrix` is taking so much RAM that it becomes inefficient. For example, if I want to create a 20million x 20million `lil_matrix`, it will blow my RAM completely. On the other hand, `csr_matrix` barely takes space. However, `csr_matrix` is allegedly inefficient for modifications. Is there any other way to get the benefit of `lil_matrix` without taking so much space in RAM? Also, why is it taking so much space in the first place, since it is supposed to be a sparse matrix?

**Note:** The real problem is actually not creating such a big matrix, but instead creating the following `list`:

```
list = [sp.lil_matrix((150,150)) for i in range(1000)]
```

which also blows up my RAM.

Comment: From experimentation, it appears lil_matrix() guesses a sparsity structure which is fairly generous. So each constructed matrix takes more memory than you /might/ need. csr_matrix is slower for indexed assignment, but more conservative in initial allocation.

Depending on your data, you might want to add dtype=int to the lil_matrix() constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I don't claim to have a full answer, but I fell like you will get there if you look at the matrix internals.

```
In [12]: s = sparse.csr_matrix((5,5))

In [13]: s.__dict__
Out[13]: 
{'_shape': (5, 5),
 'data': array([], dtype=float64),
 'format': 'csr',
 'indices': array([], dtype=int32),
 'indptr': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32),
 'maxprint': 50}

In [14]: s.indptr.nbytes
Out[14]: 24

In [15]: l = sparse.lil_matrix((5,5))

In [16]: l.__dict__
Out[16]: 
{'_shape': (5, 5),
 'data': array([[], [], [], [], []], dtype=object),
 'dtype': dtype('float64'),
 'format': 'lil',
 'maxprint': 50,
 'rows': array([[], [], [], [], []], dtype=object)}

In [17]: l.data.nbytes
Out[17]: 40

In [18]: l.rows.nbytes
Out[18]: 40
```

Comment: That was helpful. So basically, `lil_matrix` is not sparse at all, since it's initializing the same amount of space that a normal matrix would. What's the point in using it in the first place?

Comment: @Michael, `lil_matrix` is certainly sparse, it just stores information differently from `csr_matrix`. A normal 5 by 5 dense matrix containing `np.float` would take 200 bytes. You can read about advantages and disadvantages of `lil_matrix` here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html